# In App Purchase implementation in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am doing the In App Purchase Functionality in sample App from [this](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html) tutorial.
and i have also read about it from the following links

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html

I have set my own public key from publisher account.

When i started to App it works fine and it is successfully get connected with the Android Market.
But i pressed accept& buy option. i am getting the following error.

```
12-29 12:50:27.694: ERROR/BillingService(3741): Signature verification failed.
12-29 12:50:27.698: WARN/BillingService(3741): signature does not match data.
12-29 12:50:27.706: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3741): Shutting down VM
12-29 12:50:27.706: WARN/dalvikvm(3741): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.blundell.test.BillingReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2821)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at com.blundell.test.BillingHelper.verifyPurchase(BillingHelper.java:249)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at com.blundell.test.BillingReceiver.purchaseStateChanged(BillingReceiver.java:46)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at com.blundell.test.BillingReceiver.onReceive(BillingReceiver.java:29)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
12-29 12:50:27.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3741):     ... 10 more
```

**Here is the Code for same:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.PendingIntent.CanceledException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import com.android.vending.billing.IMarketBillingService;
import com.blundell.test.BillingSecurity.VerifiedPurchase;
import com.blundell.test.C.ResponseCode;


public class BillingHelper {



    private static final String TAG = "BillingService";



    private static IMarketBillingService mService;

    private static Context mContext;

    private static Handler mCompletedHandler;



    protected static VerifiedPurchase latestPurchase;



    protected static void instantiateHelper(Context context, IMarketBillingService service) {

        mService = service;

        mContext = context;

    }



    protected static void setCompletedHandler(Handler handler){

        mCompletedHandler = handler;

    }



    protected static boolean isBillingSupported() {

        if (amIDead()) {

            return false;

        }

        Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("CHECK_BILLING_SUPPORTED");

        if (mService != null) {

            try {

                Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);

                ResponseCode code = ResponseCode.valueOf((Integer) response.get("RESPONSE_CODE"));

                Log.i(TAG, "isBillingSupported response was: " + code.toString());

                if (ResponseCode.RESULT_OK.equals(code)) {

                    return true;

                } else {

                    return false;

                }

            } catch (RemoteException e) {

                Log.e(TAG, "isBillingSupported response was: RemoteException", e);

                return false;

            }

        } else {

            Log.i(TAG, "isBillingSupported response was: BillingService.mService = null");

            return false;

        }

    }



    /**

     * A REQUEST_PURCHASE request also triggers two asynchronous responses (broadcast intents). 

     * First, the Android Market application sends a RESPONSE_CODE broadcast intent, which provides error information about the request. (which I ignore)

     * Next, if the request was successful, the Android Market application sends an IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast intent. 

     * This message contains a notification ID, which you can use to retrieve the transaction details for the REQUEST_PURCHASE

     * @param activityContext

     * @param itemId

     */

    protected static void requestPurchase(Context activityContext, String itemId){

        if (amIDead()) {

            return;

        }

        Log.i(TAG, "requestPurchase()");

        Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("REQUEST_PURCHASE");

        request.putString("ITEM_ID", itemId);

        try {

            Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);



            //The RESPONSE_CODE key provides you with the status of the request

            Integer responseCodeIndex   = (Integer) response.get("RESPONSE_CODE");

            //The PURCHASE_INTENT key provides you with a PendingIntent, which you can use to launch the checkout UI

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = (PendingIntent) response.get("PURCHASE_INTENT");

            //The REQUEST_ID key provides you with a unique request identifier for the request

            Long requestIndentifier     = (Long) response.get("REQUEST_ID");

            Log.i(TAG, "current request is:" + requestIndentifier);

            C.ResponseCode responseCode = C.ResponseCode.valueOf(responseCodeIndex);

            Log.i(TAG, "REQUEST_PURCHASE Sync Response code: "+responseCode.toString());



            startBuyPageActivity(pendingIntent, new Intent(), activityContext);

        } catch (RemoteException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Failed, internet error maybe", e);

            Log.e(TAG, "Billing supported: "+isBillingSupported());

        }

    }



    /**

     * A GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION request also triggers two asynchronous responses (broadcast intents). 

     * First, the Android Market application sends a RESPONSE_CODE broadcast intent, which provides status and error information about the request.  (which I ignore)

     * Next, if the request was successful, the Android Market application sends a PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast intent. 

     * This message contains detailed transaction information. 

     * The transaction information is contained in a signed JSON string (unencrypted). 

     * The message includes the signature so you can verify the integrity of the signed string

     * @param notifyIds

     */

    protected static void getPurchaseInformation(String[] notifyIds){

        if (amIDead()) {

            return;

        }

        Log.i(TAG, "getPurchaseInformation()");

        Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION");

        // The REQUEST_NONCE key contains a cryptographically secure nonce (number used once) that you must generate.

        // The Android Market application returns this nonce with the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast intent so you can verify the integrity of the transaction information.

        request.putLong("NONCE", BillingSecurity.generateNonce());

        // The NOTIFY_IDS key contains an array of notification IDs, which you received in the IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast intent.

        request.putStringArray("NOTIFY_IDS", notifyIds);

        try {

            Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);



            //The REQUEST_ID key provides you with a unique request identifier for the request

            Long requestIndentifier     = (Long) response.get("REQUEST_ID");

            Log.i(TAG, "current request is:" + requestIndentifier);

            //The RESPONSE_CODE key provides you with the status of the request

            Integer responseCodeIndex   = (Integer) response.get("RESPONSE_CODE");

            C.ResponseCode responseCode = C.ResponseCode.valueOf(responseCodeIndex);

            Log.i(TAG, "GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION Sync Response code: "+responseCode.toString());



        } catch (RemoteException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Failed, internet error maybe", e);

            Log.e(TAG, "Billing supported: "+isBillingSupported());

        }

    }



    /**

     * To acknowledge that you received transaction information you send a

     * CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS request.

     * 

     * A CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS request triggers a single asynchronous response�a RESPONSE_CODE broadcast intent. 

     * This broadcast intent provides status and error information about the request.

     * 

     * Note: As a best practice, you should not send a CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS request for a purchased item until you have delivered the item to the user. 

     * This way, if your application crashes or something else prevents your application from delivering the product,

     * your application will still receive an IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast intent from Android Market indicating that you need to deliver the product

     * @param notifyIds

     */

    protected static void confirmTransaction(String[] notifyIds) {

        if (amIDead()) {

            return;

        }

        Log.i(TAG, "confirmTransaction()");

        Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS");

        request.putStringArray("NOTIFY_IDS", notifyIds);

        try {

            Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);



            //The REQUEST_ID key provides you with a unique request identifier for the request

            Long requestIndentifier     = (Long) response.get("REQUEST_ID");

            Log.i(TAG, "current request is:" + requestIndentifier);



            //The RESPONSE_CODE key provides you with the status of the request

            Integer responseCodeIndex   = (Integer) response.get("RESPONSE_CODE");

            C.ResponseCode responseCode = C.ResponseCode.valueOf(responseCodeIndex);



            Log.i(TAG, "CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS Sync Response code: "+responseCode.toString());

        } catch (RemoteException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Failed, internet error maybe", e);

            Log.e(TAG, "Billing supported: " + isBillingSupported());

        }

    }



    /**

     * 

     * Can be used for when a user has reinstalled the app to give back prior purchases. 

     * if an item for sale's purchase type is "managed per user account" this means google will have a record ofthis transaction

     * 

     * A RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request also triggers two asynchronous responses (broadcast intents). 

     * First, the Android Market application sends a RESPONSE_CODE broadcast intent, which provides status and error information about the request. 

     * Next, if the request was successful, the Android Market application sends a PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast intent. 

     * This message contains the detailed transaction information. The transaction information is contained in a signed JSON string (unencrypted).

     * The message includes the signature so you can verify the integrity of the signed string

     * @param nonce

     */

    protected static void restoreTransactionInformation(Long nonce) {

        if (amIDead()) {

            return;

        }

        Log.i(TAG, "confirmTransaction()");

        Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS");

        // The REQUEST_NONCE key contains a cryptographically secure nonce (number used once) that you must generate

        request.putLong("NONCE", nonce);

        try {

            Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);



            //The REQUEST_ID key provides you with a unique request identifier for the request

            Long requestIndentifier     = (Long) response.get("REQUEST_ID");

            Log.i(TAG, "current request is:" + requestIndentifier);



            //The RESPONSE_CODE key provides you with the status of the request

            Integer responseCodeIndex   = (Integer) response.get("RESPONSE_CODE");

            C.ResponseCode responseCode = C.ResponseCode.valueOf(responseCodeIndex);

            Log.i(TAG, "RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS Sync Response code: "+responseCode.toString());

        } catch (RemoteException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Failed, internet error maybe", e);

            Log.e(TAG, "Billing supported: " + isBillingSupported());

        }

    }



    private static boolean amIDead() {

        if (mService == null || mContext == null) {

            Log.e(TAG, "BillingHelper not fully instantiated");

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }



    private static Bundle makeRequestBundle(String method) {

        Bundle request = new Bundle();

        request.putString("BILLING_REQUEST", method);

        request.putInt("API_VERSION", 1);

        request.putString("PACKAGE_NAME", mContext.getPackageName());

        return request;

    }



    /**

     * 

     * 

     * You must launch the pending intent from an activity context and not an application context

     * You cannot use the singleTop launch mode to launch the pending intent

     * @param pendingIntent

     * @param intent

     * @param context

     */

    private static void startBuyPageActivity(PendingIntent pendingIntent, Intent intent, Context context){

        //TODO add above 2.0 implementation with reflection, for now just using 1.6 implem



        // This is on Android 1.6. The in-app checkout page activity will be on its

        // own separate activity stack instead of on the activity stack of

        // the application.

        try {

            pendingIntent.send(context, 0, intent);         

        } catch (CanceledException e){

            Log.e(TAG, "startBuyPageActivity CanceledException");

        }

    }



    protected static void verifyPurchase(String signedData, String signature) {

        **ArrayList<VerifiedPurchase> purchases = BillingSecurity.verifyPurchase(signedData, signature);
        latestPurchase = purchases.get(0);**



        confirmTransaction(new String[]{latestPurchase.notificationId});



        if(mCompletedHandler != null){

            mCompletedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

        } else {

            Log.e(TAG, "verifyPurchase error. Handler not instantiated. Have you called setCompletedHandler()?");

        }

    }



    public static void stopService(){

        mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, BillingService.class));

        mService = null;

        mContext = null;

        mCompletedHandler = null;

        Log.i(TAG, "Stopping Service");

    }

}
```

Where i am doing the wrong ?? please share your idea??

Thanks

Comment: Can't say anything without the code, especially the part of it where the exception arises. Please paste the code to make your question clearer.

Comment: Hi Egor, there is a link on "this" word, there u can find the whole sample code.

Comment: So you want me to browse through all this code to find the line where your exception is thrown? I'll be glad to help you, but I feel it would cost me too much time.

Comment: I think i misunderstood the thing, sorry for that, here is the code for same, where i am getting the exception.  Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: OK, and specify the line where the exception is thrown at, please.

Comment: Exception comes in the following lines in verifyPurchase(..) method.      **ArrayList<VerifiedPurchase> purchases = BillingSecurity.verifyPurchase(signedData, signature);
        latestPurchase = purchases.get(0);**

Comment: Case is that purchases is null, means you don't have any verified purchases at the time. If it can possibly be null, as stated in the app's logic, then you should check it before calling purchases.get(0). If it should not be null - then you should check the code for any errors in logic.

Comment: Hi Egor, Thanks for your response, I resolved this issue by uploading my application in Android Market as unpublished app.

Comment: Himanshu my app is published but still i am getting this null pointer... Please tell me how you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception seems to be caused in the signature verification.

Are you following all the steps for testing Android In-app billing?

- Build your app in release mode and sign it.
- Upload the release version to Android Market, not publish, and create the product list.
- Install the application onto your device and make a test account primary on your device.

Comment: Ups, sorry, I've just see in the collapsed comments that you found the solution by your own.